# How can I force Rails (2.3.x) MemCacheStore to read a value from the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

Long story short: I have some controller logic that requests a value from the cache X times, expecting to get a different value on subsequent requests if it has in fact changed on the cache server in between *cache* requests (this is all within the context of a single *HTTP* request).

However it seems that Rails `MemCacheStore` wraps itself with `Strategy::LocalCache` so no matter how many times I request the value it will always return the first value it pulled from the server regardless if that value has changed on the server in between requests.

I was hoping there was some undocumented `:force` option for the `read()` method, but no such luck.

So my next hope was to monkey-patch it somehow to get what I needed but I'm stumped there.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain if this will work but worth a try:

```
cache.send(:bypass_local_cache) { cache.read("bar")}
```

Where `bar` is the key you are trying to access.

Note: `bypass_local_cache` is a private method.

Comment: Unfortunately bypass_local_cache was introduced in activesupport-3.0.0 and as noted in the title I'm stuck on 2.3.x.  However I might be able to back-port it so I'll look into that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working (thanks to @KandadaBoggu suggestion) by back-porting and monkey-patching the `bypass_local_cache` feature from `activesupport` 3.0

```
module ActiveSupport
  module Cache
    module Strategy
      module LocalCache
        protected
        def bypass_local_cache
          save_cache = Thread.current[thread_local_key]
          begin
            Thread.current[thread_local_key] = nil
            yield
          ensure
            Thread.current[thread_local_key] = save_cache
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can avoid the nested statements by referring to module using the full name, i.e. `module ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache`.